# How does the Ring of Greater Counterspells interact with the Mordenkainen's Disjunction spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, counterspelling

When dealing with other spells that a Wizard really doesn't want to be caught unaware by, I see the Ring of Greater Counterspells recommended as near-mandatory equipment. Yet, in discussions of Mordenkainen's Disjunction, I never see it mentioned at all.

Is there some game mechanic that prevents them from interacting? Or have I missed a very obvious reason why this solution is never mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a *ring of greater counterspells* will protect against *Mordenkainen’s disjunction*, and in games where *disjunction* sees use, that’s a very common, and commonly-recommended, choice.

In games that aren’t high enough in level, or are avoiding *disjunction*, a *ring of counterspells* is still highly recommended, keyed to *greater dispel magic* instead.

However, a *ring of (greater) counterspells* is limited to one entry at a time, and particularly in the case of 9th-level  spells, there are limits on how many you can reasonably prepare. You also have just two ring slots—if you were to get a *ring of greater counterspells* for *disjunction* and a *ring of counterspells* for *greater dispel magic*, that’s all your rings. So it’s a costly and imperfect defense.

Comment: Would it work against disjunction? The spell is not cast upon the wearer, I think. It is better against GDM, because the last at least have an option to be a targeted spell.

Comment: @annoyingimp The *ring of counterspells* doesn’t talk about “targeting” per se, just that the spell is “cast upon” you. It’s not super clear, but the consensus seems to be that “including you in the area” counts here.

Comment: And the whole spell is counterspelled as a result? Or just an effect on you is cancelled? Just interested, because I used it another way.

Comment: @annoyingimp Counterspelling would prevent the entire spell.

Comment: That is what makes me suspicious about affecting AoE spells with the ring's effect. Punishing caster of AoE effect for including someone with a ring into an area seems a bit wrong, but maybe it is ok...